# Get Twitter information from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, api, twitter

**I want to get post information of a specific user from Twitter from PowerShell.**

The command used to get post information is "Invoke-RestMethod".

Please let me know the OAuth authentication procedure required at that time.

The following information has been obtained.

- ・API key
- ・API secret key
- ・Access token
- ・Access token secret

Comment: There is a powershell module for that and a detailed description, of how to use it:  https://adamtheautomator.com/twitter-module-powershell/

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to get a tweet with the module I taught.By the way, is there a way to get tweet information without using a module?

Comment: Yes, by using the api: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference. That is what the module does as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have achieved my goal.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to access the twitter api in PowerShell is to use one of the modules, that wrap around it, like [MyTwitter](https://github.com/MyTwitter/MyTwitter).

A detailed description on how to get started with the this module can be found here: https://adamtheautomator.com/twitter-module-powershell/.

If you have to avoid external modules, you can use `Invoke-RestMethod` to call the api directly.

The article linked above describes, how to create an access token and the api reference can be found here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference

Answer (score 0):

Another option is PSTwitterAPI. It provides a function for +125 Twitter API endpoints.

```
Import-Module PSTwitterAPI

$OAuthSettings = @{
  ApiKey = ''
  ApiSecret = ''
  AccessToken = ''
  AccessTokenSecret = ''
}

Set-TwitterOAuthSettings @OAuthSettings

# Use one of the API Helpers provided:
$TwitterUser = Get-TwitterUsers_Lookup -screen_name 'mkellerman'

# Send tweet to your timeline:
Send-TwitterStatuses_Update -status "Hello World!! @mkellerman #PSTwitterAPI"

# Send DM to a user:
$Event = Send-TwitterDirectMessages_EventsNew -recipient_id $TwitterUser.Id -text "Hello @$($TwitterUser.screen_name)!! #PSTwitterAPI"

# Get the tweets you would see on your timeline:
$TwitterStatuses = Get-TwitterStatuses_HomeTimeline -count 100

# Get tweets from someone elses timeline (what they tweeted):
$TwitterStatuses = Get-TwitterStatuses_UserTimeline -screen_name 'mkellerman' -count 400

# Search for tweets:
$Tweets = Get-TwitterSearch_Tweets -q '#powershell' -count 400
```

For more info: https://github.com/mkellerman/PSTwitterAPI